# C# - On double click on listbox item

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a ListBox containing two items:

Item1
Item2

If I double click on Item1 a message should pop up with the text "Hello!". If I double click Item2 a message should pop up with the text "Bye!".

Whith the code below I'm obviously doing something wrong...

```
private void ListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (ListBox.SelectedIndex = 1)
{
MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}

if (ListBox.SelectedIndex = 2)
{
MessageBox.Show("Bye!");
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Lists and arrays are zero based so you should check for index 0 and
2. `=` is an assignment, you should use `==` in `if` statements

   ```
   private void ListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
     }

     if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == 1)  
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Bye!");
     }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

Use a zero based index

```
private void ListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
  }

  if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Bye!");
  }  
}
```